# T-SQL CTE Sequence of Weeks

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to write a recursive CTE to give me a sequence of Mondays starting at the 38th week for the next 20 weeks over 6 years. I need to graph weekly sales data for the past 6 years and thought a recursive CTE would be the best method to dynamically create a sequence of Monday dates. It's a little complicated because the season continues into the next year. Here's an example of how I would like the recordset to look:

```
9/17/2012
9/24/2012
10/1/2012
10/8/2012
10/15/2012
10/22/2012
10/29/2012
11/5/2012
11/12/2012
11/19/2012
11/26/2012
12/3/2012
12/10/2012
12/17/2012
12/24/2012
12/31/2012
1/7/2013
1/14/2013
1/21/2013
1/28/2013
2/4/2013
2/11/2013
2/18/2013
2/25/2013
9/16/2013  <-next season start
9/23/2013
9/30/2013
10/7/2013
10/14/2013
10/21/2013
10/28/2013
11/4/2013
11/11/2013
11/18/2013
11/25/2013
12/2/2013
12/9/2013
12/16/2013
12/23/2013
12/30/2013
1/6/2014
1/13/2014
1/20/2014
1/27/2014
2/3/2014
2/10/2014
2/17/2014
2/24/2014
```

I don't know if this is possible, but it seems like it could be. I was thinking I might have to use multiple CTEs to accomplish this, but am really struggling how to do this. Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I read your post over and over. I still can't understand what you need

Comment: I found it confusing to explain. I'm looking for a way to dynamically generate a result set of Mondays between the 38th week of the year and the 9th week of the following year. That would get me 1 sales season. I need to do that for 6 past seasons. I was hoping to have this list of dates generated by a CTE. It would be easy to use a recursive CTE if the dates were all in a row, but I don't want to see the dates in the months of March - August. Hope that makes a little more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured it out. valverij's answer would have worked as well. Here's what I came up with using 2 recursive CTE's. If anyone sees anything wrong with it, let me know.

```
WITH Seasons(StartDate) AS
(
    SELECT DATEADD(m, 4, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) AS StartDate UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(yy, -1, StartDate)
    FROM Seasons
    WHERE YEAR(StartDate) > YEAR(GETDATE()) - 6
),
Weeks(StartDate, WeekStartDate) AS
(
    SELECT DATEADD(d, 1 - DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(wk, 20, Seasons.StartDate)), DATEADD(wk, 20, Seasons.StartDate)), DATEADD(d, 1 - DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(wk, 20, Seasons.StartDate)), DATEADD(wk, 20, Seasons.StartDate)) AS WeekStartDate
    FROM Seasons UNION ALL
    SELECT StartDate, DATEADD(wk, 1, WeekStartDate)
    FROM Weeks
    WHERE (WeekStartDate < DATEADD(wk, 23, StartDate))
)
SELECT StartDate, WeekStartDate
FROM Weeks
ORDER BY WeekStartDate DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for Mondays in a table, you can use `DATENAME(WEEKDAY, [ColumnName])` to test for Mondays.

For example, the following code would find all of the Monday `SaleDates` in a hypothetical `Sales` table:

```
SELECT *
FROM Sales
WHERE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, SaleDate) = 'Monday'
```

From there, you could apply whatever additional conditions you need to (start date, end date, etc.)

Now, if you are just looking to generate a list of all Mondays, you can use a table variable and a `WHILE` loop:

```
DECLARE @Mondays TABLE(MondayDate datetime)
DECLARE @CurrentDate datetime = '02/07/2013' -- one year ago

WHILE @CurrentDate <= GETDATE() BEGIN
    IF DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @CurrentDate) = 'Monday'
        INSERT INTO @Mondays VALUES(@CurrentDate)
    SET @CurrentDate = @CurrentDate + 1
END

SELECT *
FROM @Mondays
```

Either way, I definitely don't think you need CTE's to accomplish this.

Comment: I thought that CTE's are faster than a while loop and an insert into a temp table. Please correct me if that's not the case.

Comment: Certainly, but it all depends on your needs. Even kicking that date back to `2/7/2000`, it only takes ~170ms. If you just need a list of Mondays for a one-off query, I think something like this is fine. If you need it for something like a stored procedure for an application, then it could potentially slow things down a bit (depending on the server load, of course)

Comment: It would be used in a stored procedure feeding an SSRS report. The user needs the ability to enter a start and end.

Comment: Is there any reason a `WHERE DATENAME(weekday, [MyDate]) = 'Monday' AND [MyDate] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate` would not work (see first example)? Unless you are working with some overly complex table schema, I'm still not sure a CTE is necessary here.

Comment: No reason it wouldn't work, but I did end up coming up with a way to due it using 2 recursive CTE's.